# How can I convert a list of dictionaries into a DataFrame?

Tags: julia

I have a list of dictionaries with a format similar to the following. The list
is generated by other functions which I don't want to change. Therefore, the
existance of the list and its dicts can be taken as a given.

```
dictlist=[]
for i in 1:20
  push!(dictlist, Dict(:a=>i, :b=>2*i))
end
```

Is there a syntactically clean way of converting this list into a DataFrame?

Comment: Are the keys always the same? If so clarify the question to start that evplictly. If not maybe make your exams a bit more complex so it shows they could have a few options

Answer (score 5):

You can `push!` the rows (represented by the dictionaries) in

Per the [docs on row by row construction.](https://juliadata.github.io/DataFrames.jl/stable/man/getting_started/#Constructing-Row-by-Row-1)

While as the docs say this is substantially slower than column by column construction, it is not any slower than constructing the columns from the dicts yourself.

```
df = DataFrame()
for row in dictlist
    push!(df, row)
end
```

---

There is a [current proposal](https://github.com/JuliaData/Tables.jl/issues/132) 
 to make `Vector{Dict}` a Tables.jl row-table type.
If that was done (which seems likely to happen within a month or so)
Then you could just do

```
df = DataFrame(dictlist)
```

Comment: I want to point out that it's important that the keys in the Dict are Expr and not String, for example. It doesn't work otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

There's no nice direct way (that I'm aware of), but with a `DataFrame` like this, you can first convert it to a list of `NamedTuples`:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> dictlist=[]
0-element Array{Any,1}

julia> for i in 1:20
         push!(dictlist, Dict(:a=>i, :b=>2*i))
       end

julia> DataFrame([NamedTuple{Tuple(keys(d))}(values(d)) for d in dictlist])
20×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ a     │ b     │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 2     │
│ 2   │ 2     │ 4     │
│ 3   │ 3     │ 6     │
│ 4   │ 4     │ 8     │
│ 5   │ 5     │ 10    │
│ 6   │ 6     │ 12    │
│ 7   │ 7     │ 14    │
│ 8   │ 8     │ 16    │
│ 9   │ 9     │ 18    │
│ 10  │ 10    │ 20    │
│ 11  │ 11    │ 22    │
│ 12  │ 12    │ 24    │
│ 13  │ 13    │ 26    │
│ 14  │ 14    │ 28    │
│ 15  │ 15    │ 30    │
│ 16  │ 16    │ 32    │
│ 17  │ 17    │ 34    │
│ 18  │ 18    │ 36    │
│ 19  │ 19    │ 38    │
│ 20  │ 20    │ 40    │
```

Note that just today, I opened this up as an [issue in `Tables.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaData/Tables.jl/issues/132), so there may be better support for this soon.

Comment: You can construct a `NamedTuple` from a dict with `Symbol` keys simply by "splatting" it: `(; my_dict...)`

Answer (score 0):

This function provides one possible solution:

```
using DataFrames

function DictionariesToDataFrame(dictlist)
  ret = Dict()                 #Holds dataframe's columns while we build it
  #Get all unique keys from dictlist and make them entries in ret
  for x in unique([y for x in [collect(keys(x)) for x in dictlist] for y in x])
    ret[x] = []
  end
  for row in dictlist          #Loop through each row
    for (key,value) in ret     #Use ret to check all possible keys in row
      if haskey(row,key)       #Is key present in row?
        push!(value, row[key]) #Yes
      else                     #Nope
        push!(value, nothing)  #So add nothing. Keeps columns same length.
      end
    end
  end
  #Fix the data types of the columns
  for (k,v) in ret                             #Consider each column
    row_type = unique([typeof(x) for x in v])  #Get datatypes of each row
    if length(row_type)==1                     #All rows had same datatype
      row_type = row_type[1]                   #Fetch datatype
      ret[k]   = convert(Array{row_type,1}, v) #Convert column to that type
    end
  end
  #DataFrame is ready to go!
  return DataFrames.DataFrame(ret)
end

#Generate some data
dictlist=[]
for i in 1:20
  push!(dictlist, Dict("a"=>i, "b"=>2*i))
  if i>10
    dictlist[end-1]["c"]=3*i
  end
end

DictionariesToDataFrame(dictlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that does not lose data, but adds missing, for a potentially sparse frame:

```
using DataFrames

dictlist = [Dict("a" => 2), Dict("a" => 5, "b" => 8)]

keycol = unique(mapreduce(x -> collect(keys(x)), vcat, dictlist))

df = DataFrame()

df[!, Symbol("Keys")] = keycol

for (i, d) in enumerate(dictlist)
    df[!, Symbol(string(i))] = [get(d, k, missing) for k in keycol]
end

println(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference Its looks there is no method available to covert a list of dict in to dataframe. Instead we have convert the list of dict into dict of list. I mean from `[(:a => 1, :b =>2), (:a => 3, :b =>4)]` into `(:a => [1, 3], :b => [2, 4])` So we need to create such function:

```
function to_dict_of_array(data::Array, fields::Array)
    # Pre allocate the array needed for speed up in case of large dataset
    doa = Dict(Symbol(field) => Array{Any}(undef, length(data)) for field in fields)
    for (i, datum) in enumerate(data)
        for fn in fields
            sym_fn = Symbol(fn)
            doa[sym_fn][i]  = datum[fn]
        end
    end
    return doa
end
```

Then we can use that method to create dataframe.

```
array_of_dict = [Dict("a" => 1, "b" =>2), Dict("a" => 3, "b" =>4)]
required_field = ["a", "b"]
df = DataFrame(to_dict_of_array(array_of_dict, required_field));
```

Its just a conceptual example. Should be modified based on the usecase.